# Acceptance rate is wrong

Tags: support

I've looked (conceivably) everywhere, but can't figure out why my acceptance rate on serverfault.com is 86% when I've asked eight questions and accepted an answer for each one. My stackoverflow.com acceptance rate is accurate. It's not due to caching and as far as I can tell not due to any other potential issues listed at [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

No big deal either way, but seeing something conceivably technically wrong erks me and I'm curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one:

[Elevate PSFTP "put" command as root](https://serverfault.com/questions/334572/elevate-psftp-put-command-as-root)

- Community Wiki: No
- Closed: No
- Questions with no answers: No

Thus it's eligable for your acceptance rate algorithm.

Don't worry though, 86% is still good.

Comment: I see you just posted an answer, and it's now 100%

Comment: Lol. I just came back to delete/answer the question. The problem indeed was between the monitor and the chair ;-)

Comment: For the life of me, I was SURE I checked each question - I didn't want some poor answerer to go un-noted.